# jQuery Works in Iframe but not in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a page which is currently displayed in an iframe in another page. It includes a little bit of jQuery which works well this way. It displays an extra table when a button is clicked.

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="click<?php echo $i ?>" class="buttonSearchList">&nbsp;&nbsp; Enquire or Book</a>
<script>
$("a#click<?php echo $i ?>").click(function() {
$("#hiddenstuff<?php echo $i ?>").slideDown(1000),
$("a#click<?php echo $i ?>").fadeOut(500);
});
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="hiddenstuff<?php echo $i ?>" style="display:none">
*Content*
</div>
```

I would like to get rid of the iframe though, and use ajax instead. To do this I have put the following in the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#prices').load('../prices.php?hid=<?php echo $hid;?>');
});
</script>
```

The child page loads OK but the jQuery within it doesn't work. Why should that be?

Comment: Most likely the javascript is being executed too early. Best solution would be to stop putting javascript in html being loaded by ajax. Instead, put it in the success callback. You also shouldn't have a script tag for every table that does the same thing, just with a different id. Consolidate that to one with a class selector.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Sorry to be a dummy but could you explain the success callback in more detail. I've looked in up in the jQuery documentation and had a couple of stabs at it, but still no luck. jQuery is totally new to me, and I don't even have much javascript knowledge to fall back on.